# Timer looping in vba (Access)

Tags: ms-access, timer, vba

I'm trying to configure a timer to run every 3 minutes in VBA, to loop through my Access database table and validate data. I'm stuck at the point of starting the timer. I wrote this mini script to test the timer:

```
Function JobNameValidate()
MsgBox ("Hello")
'callAgain.OnTimer
End Function

Function callAgain()
callAgain.TimerInterval = 300000
Forms("HiddenForm1").OnTimer
JobNameValidate
End Function
```

It loops fine, however it loops instantly, regardless of the `TimerInterval` put in. I couldn't find any helpful documentation about this online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your form's `OnTimer` property to a string which starts with `=` followed by your function name and a pair of parentheses.

The units for `TimerInterval` are milliseconds.  So 3 minutes is 180000 (3 * 60 * 1000).

```vb
Function callAgain()
    Forms("HiddenForm1").OnTimer = "=JobNameValidate()"
    Forms("HiddenForm1").TimerInterval = 180000
End Function
```

I'm not sure why you want to do this with VBA.  You could set both those properties in the form's property sheet.  But you can do it with VBA if needed.

Comment: You would do it in VBA when you need the timer occasionally but not all of the time?

Comment: Yes, that is one possibility.  Or you could perhaps substitute a difference function as the timer action or adjust the TimerInterval duration in response to conditions you define.